# Parsing JSON data from Restful API C#

Tags: c#, api, razor

So I have implemented a C# RESTful API for a recent side project and I have noticed that when making a GET request to the API I am provided with a lot of data when I only need around 8 or so entries, specifically the newest entries.

I have narrowed down this too one of two different issues, I believe my below fall back code to be somewhat primitive following a generic class structure that is created when deseralize object is called. The main problem could be because I am using a web client to download the JSON data then passing it over, could this be more sophisticated to allow the functionality I want?

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var json = wc.DownloadString("//api call here");
    jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
}
```

I am of course using NewtonSoft Json libary here.

Or secondly could it be that I need to make changes to the controller to allow a way for me to request only the 8 newest entries? I have little knowledge of changing API's other than allowing the VS magic to happen.

I mostly seek you're advice here because I could be worried about nothing but I just think my approach is wrong and if the data starts getting larger I should be improving on my existing knowledge.

Comment: If It's api doesn't support paging or limit data, You will always get full data ,

Comment: Try to implement your API using OData so you can query the data while fetching it.

Comment: Thanks for you're comment Ramin I have been reading OData and it looks quite promising, though I would ideally like to explore the possibility of finding a solution without relocating just yet.

Comment: If you made the RESTful API and produce the output i don't see why you couldn't limit the entries with a TOP clause on the SQL query or if that's not an option, with LINQ, instead of returning MyData, return MyData.OrderByDescending(data => data.SomeDate).Take(8). Even if you're using a very high level development framework, you should be able to do this. The exactly same code applies if you wan't to do the 8 newest filtering on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide clarity on how this problem was solved it was mostly done through creating specific triggers on the existing API that allowed SQL to be run which is something that was I previously didn't know.

This allowed me to limit the amount of data that was returned through a generic sql command. A separate call was created on the API which returned all of the data and loaded the later objects into the dom using an async function.

Yes you can use SQL with api's generated by C# magic.